# Vertical menu goes to new line when padding is set by percent

Tags: html, css

Here is the fiddle, this is a vertical menu, floated to right. I have to use percent values (to have responsive design) but then the last menu goes underline. If I set it with "px" it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/aDRnn/

```
#topmenu
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    min-height: 47px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 25px;
    float: right;
}

#topmenu ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 13px 0 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

#topmenu ul li
{
    display: inline;
    padding: 15px 2.5% 17px 2.5%; /* when its set with percents, it screwes */
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#topmenu ul li:last-child
{
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#topmenu ul li:first-child
{
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

#topmenu ul li img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#topmenu a
{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 54px;
}
```

```
<div id="topmenu"><ul>
        <li class="">
            <a href="tanar">
                Nyitólap</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="diak">
                Rólunk</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="szulo">
                Szállodák</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="nyelviskola">
                Apartmanok</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="boltok">
                Gourmentteszt</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
```

Comment: something like that http://jsfiddle.net/EAEKc/ except I cant use fix widths!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/aDRnn/1/

Comment: sorry, not really, the menus must be in one line

Comment: what should happen when there is no space left on the line? horizontal scroll or this: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/aDRnn/2/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a float:right on the #topmenu, but you need a float:left to his children "ul". Also, if you want to have "li" paddings and margins, you need to also float them left.